# Navigation bar shows wrong navigation item in iOS 9.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

A `UINavigationController's` navigationBar will initially show the correct UINavigationItem, but then will revert to the previous `UINavigationIte`m every time a UIViewController is pushed onto the stack.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Push a `UIViewController` onto a `UINavigationControlle`r stack
2. Set navigationBarHidden = YES on the navigation controller
3. Push another view controller onto the navigation stack.
4. Begin an interactive pop transition and then cancel it.
5. Pop back to the previous view controller
6. Set `navigationBarHidden = NO` on the navigation controller
7. Attempt to push a view controller onto the stack

---

Looks like `-[UINavigationBar _cancelInteractiveTransition]` is getting called, even on push transitions after getting into this state? I can set a breakpoint on that symbol, and the navigation bar shows the correct navigation item before it and the wrong navigation item afterwards.

---

But what I want is that the navigation controller's navigation bar should  display the current topViewController's navigation item.

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface UINavigationController (Private)

- (void)_cancelInteractiveTransition:(float)arg1 transitionContext:(id)arg2;

@end

- (void)_cancelInteractiveTransition:(float)arg1 transitionContext:(id)arg2
{
    BOOL hidden = self.isNavigationBarHidden;
    if (hidden) {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }
    [super _cancelInteractiveTransition:arg1 transitionContext:arg2];
    if (hidden) {
        [self setNavigationBarHidden:hidden animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand on this answer at all? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Explain your answer so it will clarify in detail

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this issue on iOS10 and I'm sure it was there on iOS9, assuming we still supported it. It turned out that the issue was that at the start of the interactive transition we were setting navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO and then when it was cancelled forgetting to set it back to navigationController.navigationBarHidden=YES. It seems like the navigation bar doesn't like to be unhidden twice in a row. I would imagine that its the same for setting it to hidden twice in a row as well.  The good news is that this was not an issue with iOS11.